# Name of the bug uncovered after another bug has been fixed

Tags: terminology

How is a bug called which is revealed after another bug has been fixed?

I have a series of tests, I've written a test for the new bug, and I've made the fix. Now, another test is failing, revealing that the reference data of that test was wrong, as well as a bug in the SUT.

I think it's not a regression bug, because it's not a new bug which appears after the current bug has been fixed, but a bug which has always been there, just not visible / covered by the currently fixed bug.

Answer (score 0):

If the newly revealed bug is the one that actually causes the problem, then it might be called the "[root cause](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_cause)"

Comment: It's not the root cause, because it's about a combinatorial problem: some objects are compared pairwise. The bugs are really "at the same level of abstraction", it's just that fixing one made the other one obvious - by making another test case fail.

Answer (score 0):

I would call this a *hidden* or *concealed* bug that is revealed by fixing the bug previously concealing it.